# Implement inference bayesian network using session tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining, bayesian-networks

I am a new with machine learning. I have a final project about prediction using two algorithms, Artificial Neural Network and Bayesian Neural Network. I want to compare the prediction result between ANN and BNN. I have finished the ANN program, but I have a problem with the BNN. I try a tutorial from this link: [bayesian neural network tutorial](https://github.com/mikkokemppainen/Jupyter_notebooks/blob/master/Edward_notebook_public.ipynb). This is my ANN sample code to train and evaluate the model.

```
keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float", name="keep_prob")
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name="x")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="y")

training_epochs = 5000
display_step = 1000
batch_size = 5

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predictions, labels=y), name="cost_function")
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001, name="Adam").minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in tqdm(range(training_epochs)):
            avg_cost = 0.0
            total_batch = int(len(x_train) / batch_size)
            x_batches = np.array_split(x_train, total_batch)
            y_batches = np.array_split(y_train, total_batch)

            for i in range(total_batch):
                batch_x, batch_y = x_batches[i], y_batches[i]
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.8})
                avg_cost += c / total_batch
            if epoch % display_step == 0:
                print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

        print("Optimization Finished!")
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1), name="corr_pred")
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"), name="accuracy")
        # print('Accuracy: ', sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y: y_test}))
        print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: x_test, y: y_test, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

and this is my BNN code:

```
# Importing required libraries
from math import floor

import edward as ed
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from edward.models import Normal, NormalWithSoftplusScale
from fancyimpute import KNN
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Read data
features_dummies_nan = pd.read_csv('csv/features_dummies_with_label.csv', sep=',')


# Function: impute missing value by KNN
def impute_missing_values_by_KNN():
    home_data = features_dummies_nan[[col for col in features_dummies_nan.columns if 'hp' in col]]
    away_data = features_dummies_nan[[col for col in features_dummies_nan.columns if 'ap' in col]]
    label_data = features_dummies_nan[[col for col in features_dummies_nan.columns if 'label' in col]]

    home_filled = pd.DataFrame(KNN(3).complete(home_data))
    home_filled.columns = home_data.columns
    home_filled.index = home_data.index

    away_filled = pd.DataFrame(KNN(3).complete(away_data))
    away_filled.columns = away_data.columns
    away_filled.index = away_data.index

    data_frame_out = pd.concat([home_filled, away_filled, label_data], axis=1)

    return data_frame_out


features_dummies = impute_missing_values_by_KNN()

target = features_dummies.loc[:, 'label'].values
data = features_dummies.drop('label', axis=1)
data = data.values

perm = np.random.permutation(len(features_dummies))
data = data[perm]
target = target[perm]

train_size = 0.9

train_cnt = floor(features_dummies.shape[0] * train_size)

x_train = data[0:train_cnt]  # data_train
y_train = target[0:train_cnt]  # target_train
x_test = data[train_cnt:]  # data_test
y_test = target[train_cnt:]  # target_test

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float", name="keep_prob")
n_input = data.shape[1]  # D
n_classes = 3
n_hidden_1 = 100  # H0
n_hidden_2 = 100  # H1
n_hidden_3 = 100  # H2


def neural_network(X, W_0, W_1, W_2, W_out, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_out):
    hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W_0) + b_0)
    hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden1, W_1) + b_1)
    hidden3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden2, W_2) + b_2)
    output = tf.matmul(hidden3, W_out) + b_out
    return tf.reshape(output, [-1])


scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(x_train)

data_train_scaled = scaler.transform(x_train)
data_test_scaled = scaler.transform(x_test)

W_0 = Normal(loc=tf.zeros([n_input, n_hidden_1]), scale=5.0 * tf.ones([n_input, n_hidden_1]))
W_1 = Normal(loc=tf.zeros([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2]), scale=5.0 * tf.ones([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2]))
W_2 = Normal(loc=tf.zeros([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3]), scale=5.0 * tf.ones([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3]))
W_out = Normal(loc=tf.zeros([n_hidden_3, 1]), scale=5.0 * tf.ones([n_hidden_3, 1]))

b_0 = Normal(loc=tf.zeros(n_hidden_1), scale=5.0 * tf.ones(n_hidden_1))
b_1 = Normal(loc=tf.zeros(n_hidden_2), scale=5.0 * tf.ones(n_hidden_2))
b_2 = Normal(loc=tf.zeros(n_hidden_3), scale=5.0 * tf.ones(n_hidden_3))
b_out = Normal(loc=tf.zeros(1), scale=5.0 * tf.ones(1))

qW_0 = NormalWithSoftplusScale(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
                               scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])))
qW_1 = NormalWithSoftplusScale(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
                               scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])))
qW_2 = NormalWithSoftplusScale(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3])),
                               scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3])))
qW_out = NormalWithSoftplusScale(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, 1])),
                                 scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, 1])))

qb_0 = NormalWithSoftplusScale(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
                               scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])))
qb_1 = NormalWithSoftplusScale(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
                               scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])))
qb_2 = NormalWithSoftplusScale(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3])),
                               scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3])))
qb_out = NormalWithSoftplusScale(loc=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1])),
                                 scale=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1])))

sigma_y = 1.0

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = Normal(loc=neural_network(x, W_0, W_1, W_2, W_out, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_out), scale=sigma_y)

inference = ed.KLqp({W_0: qW_0, b_0: qb_0,
                     W_1: qW_1, b_1: qb_1,
                     W_2: qW_2, b_2: qb_2,
                     W_out: qW_out, b_out: qb_out}, data={x: x_train, y: y_train})

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.05
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step,
                                           1000, 0.3, staircase=True)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

inference.run(n_iter=5000, optimizer=optimizer, global_step=global_step)
```

But, I want to compare two algorithms result. So, I want to make some variables will be same between ANN and BNN, for example sum of epoch. Then I want to adapt my ANN code above for this BNN code section.

```
sigma_y = 1.0

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = Normal(loc=neural_network(x, W_0, W_1, W_2, W_out, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_out), scale=sigma_y)

inference = ed.KLqp({W_0: qW_0, b_0: qb_0,
                     W_1: qW_1, b_1: qb_1,
                     W_2: qW_2, b_2: qb_2,
                     W_out: qW_out, b_out: qb_out}, data={x: x_train, y: y_train})

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.05
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step,
                                           1000, 0.3, staircase=True)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

inference.run(n_iter=5000, optimizer=optimizer, global_step=global_step)
```

I have several things that I don't understand. There is `y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="y")` in ANN but in BNN is `y = Normal(loc=neural_network(x, W_0, W_1, W_2, W_out, b_0, b_1, b_2, b_out), scale=sigma_y)`. Then, there is scale in BNN but not in ANN. So, can I adapt my ANN train and test sample code to BNN sample code above? I want to make inference on BNN run like in sess.run() on ANN so I can count the BNN prediction accuracy result. Can I do that?